# Typescript - destructure dictionary entry

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have an interface defined as:

```
export interface NormalizedTag {
    [key: string]: NTag
}
```

Now, inside a function I've got an instance of such interface:

```
value: NormalizedTag = getNormalizedTag(...)
```

What's the better way to obtain both the `key: string` and the `value: NTag` as separate variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will get you the list of key-value pairs in the object, which is an array of two tuples. You could then use array destructuring to get the values. The interface you defined can have an arbitrary number of key-value pairs, but if you only need one of them, you could use the following snippet:

```
const [[key, nTag]] = Object.entries(getNormalizedTag(...));
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another doubt now. You wrote that my "Interface can have an arbitrary number of key-value pairs". So does it have any sense declaring a "wrapper" interface such as https://pastebin.com/gQTPdUkD (notice I used `NormalizedTag[]`) ?

And why using `const { ntag } = getNormalizedTag(...)` lets me have the value part?

Comment: No. If you have a single key-value pair then use a single `{key:string, value:NTag}`, if you have multiple values then either keep using the interface in the question or start using `{key:string, value:NTag}[]`. Having an array for keys and another for values tends to have problems like the arrays getting desynchronized because another programmer on the project will not know anything about the connection between those two arrays and will use them as independent ones.